# Angular.js with Jade and Express - data binding not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, pug

I'm learning AngularJS with Dan Wahlin's tutorial (http://youtu.be/i9MHigUZKEM?t=13m35s). I have the following code in my views/index.jade:

```
!!! 5
html(data-ng-app='')
  head
    title Angular Tutorial
  body
    | Name:
    br 
    input(type='text', data-ng-model='name') | {{name}}

    script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js', type='text/javascript')
```

But when I run the app, and type anything in the Name box, it does not display the text like it does in the tutorial. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your binding on the next row. The previous one sets it inside the input (which doesn't make sense).

```
input(type='text', data-ng-model='name')
| {{name}}
```

Comment: thanks! could you please explain this a little more? why does having it on the same line set it inside the input?

Comment: Compare it to placing text inside of paragraph tag: `p Foobar`.